Parsing JSON Array of Strings in Logic Apps
I have been asked to report ADF pipeline status via email from Logic Apps. I have a table containing ClientFeedID, ClientName, PipelineName, RunStatus, RunStart and RunEnd columns which I pass as JSON from ADF to Logic Apps in an attempt to generate an email summarizing status.
Input JSON as passed from ADF:
    "runPageUrl": "https://myresource.azuredatabricks.net",
    "runOutput": [
        "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"31\",\"ClientName\":\"Client1\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client1\",\"RunStatus\":\"InProgress\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T12:00:00.9008853Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"NULL\"}",
        "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"119\",\"ClientName\":\"Client2\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client2\",\"RunStatus\":\"InProgress\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T12:39:14.6654259Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"NULL\"}",
        "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"19\",\"ClientName\":\"Client3\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client3\",\"RunStatus\":\"Succeeded\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T03:48:09.2485603Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"2024-08-07T04:17:51.4093277Z\"}",
        "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"14\",\"ClientName\":\"Client4\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client4\",\"RunStatus\":\"Failed\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T13:45:00.090202Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"2024-08-07T11:22:05.9396317Z\"}"
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "executionDuration": 84,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.03333333333333333,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}

runOutput appears to be an array of strings and I need some help determining how to separate the individual columns in each element of the array.
I have made several attempts in Logic Apps using the answers from many questions on SO. My current Logic App appears as follows:
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "triggers": {
      "manual": {
        "type": "Request",
        "kind": "Http",
        "inputs": {
          "method": "POST",
          "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "runPageUrl": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "runOutput": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "executionDuration": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "durationInQueue": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "integrationRuntimeQueue": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  }
                }
              },
              "billingReference": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "activityType": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "billableDuration": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "meterType": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "duration": {
                          "type": "number"
                        },
                        "unit": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "meterType",
                        "duration",
                        "unit"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "actions": {
      "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
        "type": "ApiConnection",
        "inputs": {
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365-1']['connectionId']"
            }
          },
          "method": "post",
          "body": {
            "To": "Just.Bob@myemail.com",
            "Subject": "Pipeline Summary",
            "Body": "<p class=\"editor-paragraph\">@{body('Create_HTML_table')}</p>",
            "Importance": "Normal"
          },
          "path": "/v2/Mail"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "For_each": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Initialize_ClientFeedID": {
        "type": "InitializeVariable",
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "ClientFeedID",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {}
      },
      "Initialize_ClientName": {
        "type": "InitializeVariable",
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "ClientName",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Initialize_ClientFeedID": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        }
      },
      "For_each": {
        "type": "Foreach",
        "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
        "actions": {
          "Create_HTML_table": {
            "type": "Table",
            "inputs": {
              "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
              "format": "HTML",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "header": "ClientFeedID",
                  "value": "@variables('ClientFeedID')"
                }
              ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
              "Set_ClientFeedID": [
                "Succeeded"
              ]
            }
          },
          "Set_ClientFeedID": {
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "inputs": {
              "name": "ClientFeedID",
              "value": "@items('For_each').ClientFeedID"
            }
          }
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Parse_JSON": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "runtimeConfiguration": {
          "concurrency": {
            "repetitions": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "Parse_JSON": {
        "type": "ParseJson",
        "inputs": {
          "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
          "schema": {
            "properties": {
              "ClientFeedID": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "ClientName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "PipelineName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "RunStatus": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "RunStart": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "RunEnd": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Compose": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Compose": {
        "type": "Compose",
        "inputs": "@triggerBody()?['runOutput']",
        "runAfter": {
          "Initialize_ClientName": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
      "$connections": {
        "type": "Object",
        "defaultValue": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "$connections": {
      "value": {
        "office365-1": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubscriptions",
          "connectionId": "/subscriptions/myconnections/office365-4",
          "connectionName": "office365-4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Output from Compose:
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"31\",\"ClientName\":\"Client1\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client1\",\"RunStatus\":\"InProgress\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T12:00:00.9008853Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"NULL\"}",
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"119\",\"ClientName\":\"Client2\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client2\",\"RunStatus\":\"InProgress\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T12:39:14.6654259Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"NULL\"}",
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"19\",\"ClientName\":\"Client3\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client3\",\"RunStatus\":\"Succeeded\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T03:48:09.2485603Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"2024-08-07T04:17:51.4093277Z\"}",
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"14\",\"ClientName\":\"Client4\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client4\",\"RunStatus\":\"Failed\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T13:45:00.090202Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"2024-08-07T11:22:05.9396317Z\"}"
]

Identical to Input
Schema for Parse JSON:
  "properties": {
    "ClientFeedID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ClientName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "PipelineName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "RunStatus": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "RunStart": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "RunEnd": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}

Output from Parse JSON:
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"31\",\"ClientName\":\"Client1\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client1\",\"RunStatus\":\"InProgress\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T12:00:00.9008853Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"NULL\"}",
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"119\",\"ClientName\":\"Client2\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client2\",\"RunStatus\":\"InProgress\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T12:39:14.6654259Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"NULL\"}",
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"19\",\"ClientName\":\"Client3\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client3\",\"RunStatus\":\"Succeeded\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T03:48:09.2485603Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"2024-08-07T04:17:51.4093277Z\"}",
  "{\"ClientFeedID\":\"14\",\"ClientName\":\"Client4\",\"PipelineName\":\"parent-client4\",\"RunStatus\":\"Failed\",\"RunStart\":\"2024-08-07T13:45:00.090202Z\",\"RunEnd\":\"2024-08-07T11:22:05.9396317Z\"}"
]

Set ClientFeedID in For each returns:
InvalidTemplate
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Set_ClientFeedID' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'items('For_each').ClientFeedID' cannot be evaluated because property 'ClientFeedID' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
My expectation was that I could grab the set of values from each array element and use them as row values within the email. As a newbie to Logic Apps, I am clearly lost in the weeds and have spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to get this running.
Thank You in advance for any and all help!

I have used the given workflow and it worked for me.


Set Concurrency control to 1 in For-Each loop.

Using below schema in Parse_JSON action.
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "ClientFeedID": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ClientName": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "PipelineName": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "RunStatus": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "RunStart": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "RunEnd": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Append_to_string_variable_1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "name": "Email Table",
                    "value": "</table>"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Email Table",
                            "value": "<tr>\n    <td>@{body('Parse_JSON')?['ClientFeedID']}</td>\n    <td>@{body('Parse_JSON')?['ClientName']}</td>\n    <td>@{body('Parse_JSON')?['PipelineName']}</td>\n    <td>@{body('Parse_JSON')?['RunStatus']}</td>\n    <td>@{body('Parse_JSON')?['RunStart']}</td>\n    <td>@{body('Parse_JSON')?['RunEnd']}</td>\n</tr>\n"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Parse_JSON": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToStringVariable"
                    },
                    "Parse_JSON": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "content": "@items('For_each')",
                            "schema": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "ClientFeedID": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "ClientName": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "PipelineName": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "RunEnd": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "RunStart": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "RunStatus": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "type": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "ParseJson"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@triggerBody()?['runOutput']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Set_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Email Table",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p class=\"editor-paragraph\">@{variables('Email Table')}</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Test Report",
                        "To": "********"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Append_to_string_variable_1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Set_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "name": "Email Table",
                    "value": "<table border='1'><tr><th>ClientFeedID</th><th>ClientName</th><th>PipelineName</th><th>RunStatus</th><th>RunStart</th><th>RunEnd</th></tr>"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "SetVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/0e******e7c/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/0e8********e7c/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




Hi Ikhtesam - I am unable to see the images you provided but I did pull the code over to my Logic App including the schema definition for Parse JSON. Running against the data above, the app returns "message": "Invalid type. Expected Object but got Array."
from Parse JSON. I'm certain the error is something I've done improperly - do you have a suggestion on a next step?

Ikhtesam - verifying I did check concurrency control. It is set on with a limit of 1.

@JustBob try to check your network connectivity if you are unable to see the screenshots. Verify the input of for each loop to be triggerBody()?['runOutput'] and then add Parse json action which will have items('For_each') input

Looking much better! Problem with the Append String inside the For Each loop - I tried pasting in the code you supplied but the designer tells me it's invalid. I've also tried @concat('\n', body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['ClientFeedID'], '\n', body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['ClientName'], '\n', body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['PipelineName'], '\n', body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['RunStatus'], '\n', body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['RunStart'], '\n',body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['RunEnd'], '\n\n').  Still fails

Ikhtesam - network is good. Verified input to For Each and Parse Json:
"type": "Foreach",
"foreach": "@triggerBody()?['runOutput']",
"type": "ParseJson",
"inputs": {"content": "@items('For_each')",
Parse Json is outputting the correct data!!!
I'm pretty excited to see this as close as it is - I'll keep trying variations on the Append and see if I can get this resolved   :)
Thank You SO Much!

Ikhtesam - IT WORKS! Not sure what I did wrong but that's on me - not you. Again, Thank You, Thank You, Thank You!
